# Azure .net Web app backend port and ip address

Tags: c#, .net, azure

It might be a really dumb question, but I cant find the correct answer to my question.
I have hosted web app on azure. angularjs/.net framework project.

Now we have to send specific request from backend to specific IP address.
To reach that specific address we have to whitelist our azure webapp back end IP and port.

In Azure I found virtual IP and outbound IP addresses list.
Do I whitelist that virtual IP address or that list of outbound addresses?

And where do I find port of back end?

Sorry for stupid question in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

there are not stupid questions ;)

You have to provide all the outbound IP to the white list. There are ways to allow out to Interntet with only one IP if you need. I did a video some time ago about this, is in spanish but maybe can help you:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0SjBe2R7a6g&t=708s&ab_channel=AzureNoticias